# Why in Android 2.1 or other versions the seekbar looks so odd

Tags: android, android-layout

Why the standard seekbar in Android 2.1 or other version looks so odd. I mean the Thumb image begins outside the container. Am I doing something wrong or this is a normal behavior. How to correct this behavior ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default thumb image. You can set the thumb image of seekbar. create a small image which you like to set as thumb image. using the following code

```
android:thumb="@drawable/music_player_playerhead"
```

Comment: I accept the answer but for me it remains odd even if it is standard UI.

Comment: I did the same think in my project.